# Momentum in Free Scalar Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I have a few issues with making the transition between these:

$\phi(x)=\int{\frac{d^3p}{2\pi^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\vec{p}}}}(a_{\vec{p}}e^{i \vec{p} \vec{x}}+ a^{\dagger}_{\vec{p}}e^{-i \vec{p} \vec{x}}})$

$\pi(x)=\int{\frac{d^3p}{2\pi^3}(-i)\sqrt{\frac{\omega_{\vec{p}}}{2}}(a_{\vec{p}}e^{i \vec{p} \vec{x}}- a^{\dagger}_{\vec{p}}e^{-i \vec{p} \vec{x}}})$.

So from the Lagrangian of the real scalar field, we get

$\pi(x)=\partial_0 \phi(x)$

which just means differentiating our $\phi(x)$ w.r.t time. But where does the $-i$ come from (as in the minus sign)? Also aren't the exponentials independent of time as $\vec{p} \vec{x}$ isn't a four vector? So now I'm wondering where the $\omega_{\vec{p}}$ has come from as well!

Comment: You should write $p \cdot x$, instead of $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}$, because these are 4-vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you represent the operators in the Schrödinger or Heisenberg picture. In the Schrödinger picture, there is no explicit time-dependence of the operators. Hence, the conjugate momentum is *not* given by the time derivative of the field. The concrete form is rather given by analogy to the position and momentum operators of a harmonic oscillator:

$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}(a+a^\dagger)$$
$$p=-i\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2}}(a-a^\dagger).$$

In the Heisenberg picture, the operators acquire an explicit time-dependence, i.e.

$$\phi(x)\rightarrow e^{iHt}\phi(x) e^{-iHt}.$$

In this case, taking the derivative with respect to time makes sense, and the relation between the field and its conjugate momentum can be shown to hold.

Comment: But can't we just use $\pi(x)=\partial_0 \phi(x)$ like my questions asks?

Comment: No. At this point, the operator $\phi(x)$ does not depend explicitly on time.

Comment: Ah ok I understand now! So when, for example again, Peskin and Schroeder just state $\phi(\vec{x})$ and $\pi(\vec{x})$, there isn't an easy way to get one from the other?

Comment: @user13223423: That is how I understood it.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion arises from a misunderstanding of the mode expansion of the field.

For a real scalar field we usually write the Fourier expansion as
$$\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}a^\dagger v_k e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}+a v_k^* e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$$
However, now we still have to find the mode functions $v_k$ and $v_k^*$! These are solutions to the Klein-Gordon equation in Fourier space:
$$(\partial_t^2+\omega^2)\phi_k=0,\hspace{2.5cm}\omega^2=|\vec{k}|^2+m^2 $$
Now, you can easily check that 
$$v_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega}}e^{-i\omega t}$$
is a solution (the constant is there because it will make the measure of the mode expansion Lorentz invariant). This leads to the full mode expansion
$$\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2\omega}}a^\dagger e^{ikx}+a e^{-ikx} $$
where $kx=k_\mu x^\mu=\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t$. As you see, your problem was not realizing that the exponents DO contain four-vectors even though it's just a Fourier expansion in the spatial dimension.

A very clear discussion of mode functions in flat space as well as the more general case when spacetime is curved is found in chapter 9 of Carroll's book on general relativity. I also suspect that most QFT books will have at least some sort of discussion of this result.

EDIT: As mentioned in another answer, I should have specified that I will be working in the Heisenberg picture, as is conventional in QFT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why do Peskin and Schroeder, for example, have $\vec{p}\vec{x}$ in the exponent rather than $px$ (dot product of course)?

Comment: @user13223423 I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, but it might be as simple as an issue with notation.

Comment: Well $px=Et-\vec{p}\vec{x}$, so it's important to know which we're using.

Comment: @user13223423: My answer is consistent with the notation in Peskin and Schroeder, where the distinction between the two pictures is made.